# Mysql Insert form into database table PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem.. I tried today a lot to make this working but it seems to be impossible for me.. so I decided to ask help here. So I have a form which needs to be added on database table when submit button is pressed.
This is php code I currently use.. I removed my tries btw:

```html
<?php
 $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=', '', '');
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM games LIMIT 10";
 foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) { 
?>
```

my HTML code (form):

```html
<form class="form-group" method="POST" action="">
 <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
  <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px;">
   <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Game Title</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="" name="gtitle" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputPassword1">YouTube Link</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="" name="ytlink" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Link Source</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="ex: GLEAM, DLH, FAILMID, HRKGAME, INDIEGALA, OTHER, STEAM" name="slink" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Link to Free Steam Keys</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="KEY MUST GIVE +1 TO THE STEAM LIBRARY GAME COUNT" name="keysl" />
  </div>
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Steam App ID</label>
  <div class="input-group" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
   <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">http://store.steampowered.com/app/</span>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" placeholder="App ID" name="appid" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Categories</label>
   <div class="checkbox">

    <label class="radio-inline">
     <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1" /> 1
     <h4><span class="label label-success">Keys Available</span></h4>
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
     <input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2" /> 2
     <h4><span class="label label-danger">No Keys left</span></h4>
    </label>


   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="insert">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </div>

</form>
```

Thank those who help me.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: You will have to use an INSERT statement to insert into the database. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and in the radio button put value as '1' and '2' instead of 'option1' and 'option2'

```
        if(isset($_POST['insert']))
    {
        $game_title=$_POST['gtitle']; 
        $youtube_link=$_POST['ytlink'];
        $link_source=$_POST['slink'];
        $link_steam_keys=$_POST['keysl'];
        $app_id=$_POST['appid'];
        $categories=$_POST['inlineRadioOptions'];

        $query_ins="INSERT INTO tbl_game(game_title,youtube_link,link_source,link_steam_keys,app_id,categories) VALUES(:game_title,:youtube_link,:link_source,:link_steam_keys,:app_id,:categories)";
        $stmt_query=$dbh->prepare($query_ins);
        $games_ins=$stmt_query->execute(array(":game_title"=>$game_title,":youtube_link"=>$youtube_link,":link_source"=>$link_source,":link_steam_keys"=>$link_steam_keys,":app_id"=>$app_id,":categories"=>$categories));
        if(!$games_ins)
        {
            $error=$stmt_query->errorInfo();
            echo $error['2'];
        }
    }
```

Comment: My only input on this answer would be to add conditions such as:

`if (!empty($_POST['gtitle'])) {
 // add code
} else {
echo "Fill in title";`

Comment: Instead of that you can directly right 'required' attribute in the input tag.example:<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="" name="gtitle" required="required"/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the POST variables after submitting in your PHP code. If the form is submitted, take the post values and just run an INSERT query.

See [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: I'm newbie so I can't make this by myself.